# Finding the Area bounded by 1 function and 2 lines

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Find the area bounded by $y = e^{x}$, $y = e^{2}$ and $x = 0$

I found the area by integrating the function $e^2 - e^x$ with the x-bounds of $0$ to $2$, which turned out to be $e^{2} + 1$.

$$\int_0^2 (e^2 - e^x)dx$$

However, the answer that is given in the packet is $e^{4} + e - 2e^{2}$. I can't figure out it the integral that I set up is wrong or if the answer that is given in the packet is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your integration. You should have gotten $e^2+1$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales You're right it should be plus not minus, but is it fine otherwise?

Comment: Well, you did not show how you got $e^2-1$, so I cannot really say whether it was correct otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by your book is wrong. As John Wayland Bales pointed out in the comments section, you should have gotten the following:

$$
\int_{0}^{2}\left(e^2-e^x\right)\,dx=\left[e^2x-e^x\right]_{0}^{2}=
2e^2-e^2-\left(0-e^0\right)=\\
2e^2-e^2-(-1)=e^2+1.
$$